# Use PowerShell to manage a SharePoint server from a client

Tags: 2007, powershell

Sorry if this has been asked frequently, but can anyone provide guidance on how to use PowerShell to manage a SharePoint server from a client machine (ie - PowerShell not running directly on the server)?

Answer (score 2):

If you Google, there's a lot of blog posts about standing up PS for SP2007. This post should get you going: http://www.sharepointdevwiki.com/display/public/Getting+started+with+PowerShell+and+SharePoint

Comment: Thanks, webdes03, I did find that post too, but it doesn't apply to my question as he assumes (see the assumptions) that you are running on the PS server.  I would like to know how to get PS to manage SP from a client (Windows 7 to be precise).  With SCOM and also with SQL, this is a separate installation, but nothing is readily apparent regarding SP 2007.